# Resize TableLayoutPanel rows only as cells are dynamically populated

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, tablelayoutpanel, autosize

I have a TableLayoutPanel, `ug_degrees`, with 3 columns and 1 row. Each cell gets dynamically populated with another TableLayoutPanel, `degreePanel`, containing 1 label and 1 textbox.

I need to get my layout to look something like this:

[image]

Right now my layout looks like this:

[image]

I'm at a loss for why I have those giant gaps between the cells, and why the row will not expand to fill its contents (a label & a textbox). I have tried to set the whole TableLayoutPanel's autosize property to true, but the columns get resized, even if I set only the rows' sizetype to autosize as well.

The properties behind the table shown are default. All non-default properties are customized in C# below.

```
// Dynamically load undergraduate degrees
int row = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < degrees.undergraduate.Count; i++) {
    // Create and populate panel for each degree
    TableLayoutPanel degreePanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
    degreePanel.ColumnCount = 1;
    degreePanel.RowCount = 2;
    degreePanel.AutoSize = true;
    foreach (RowStyle style in degreePanel.RowStyles) {
        style.SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize;
    }
    degreePanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    //degreePanel.Margin = new Padding(0);

    Label degTitle = new Label();
    degTitle.Text = degrees.undergraduate[i].title;
    degTitle.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    TextBox degDesc = new TextBox();
    degDesc.ReadOnly = true;
    degDesc.Multiline = true;
    degDesc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    degDesc.Text = degrees.undergraduate[i].description;
    SizeF size = degDesc.CreateGraphics()
                .MeasureString(degDesc.Text,
                                degDesc.Font,
                                degDesc.Width,
                                new StringFormat(0));
    degDesc.Height = (int)size.Height;

    degreePanel.Controls.Add(degTitle, 0, 0);
    degreePanel.Controls.Add(degDesc, 0, 1);
    ug_degrees.Controls.Add(degreePanel, i, row);

    // Resize rows and columns (only after adding controls)
    foreach (RowStyle style in ug_degrees.RowStyles) {
        style.SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize;
    }

    // Jump to next row if current row is full
    if ((i+1) % 3 == 0) {
        row++;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code that creates the `ug_degrees` table?

Comment: I used Designer to create ug_degrees, and it has all the default values. It also has 3 columns and 1 row.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm not familiar enough with the winforms designer without testing it, but I would suggest checking all values there as well.

Comment: I'm hoping to set any values in C# since the table is populated dynamically

Comment: You can try setting values on `ug_degrees` after it's created. My point is, regardless of when/how it's created, a lot of times UI issues come down to setting a value on the container, instead of on the individual item.

Comment: What values might I need to set to fix the issues I'm having?

Comment: Scratch that. Try setting `degreePanel.Dock` to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `degreePanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`

Comment: Omg so simple. Thank you!